# ASP.NET MVC Calendar Design

Tags: asp.net-mvc, calendar

I want to design a calendar in asp.net mvc and I want to take month information as a string in address bar.  What should I do?  And after that I have to show this month from index.aspx.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

It's a little unclear what you're trying to do. If you're trying to present a calendar so that a user can input a date, I'd use [jQueryUI's datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/). The default style looks pretty nice, it's simple to use, and it works really well.

After re-reading your question, it seems you want your URL to be in some sort of date format. If this is the case, you need a custom route, like the one in [this article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-custom-routes-cs). After you have created your custom route, printing the date is rather simple: pass the month part of the date from your controller down to your view and display it.